# SQL SERVER -- Finding all Values in column A based on Column B

Tags: loops

```
       Column A    Column B    Column C
Row1     1,3,4         4         0
Row2     2,5,6         6         0
Row3     1,2,3         3         1
```

So, what I want to do is find the easiest way to check when column A, which is supposed to have the values of 1,2,3, and 4, by using column B, and return a 1 if Column A has all of the numbers into a new column C.

So for row 1, and row 2, Column C would be 0, because neither of them are storing all of the values that they are supposed to have. (Row 1 was supposed to have1,2,3,4, and row2 was supposed to have 1,2,3,4,5,6). Row 3 column C would have a 1, because it has all the values it is supposed to have. I can't just count the number of values either, because sometimes there are repeated values in column A.

I am trying to code this in a way that isn't too long, because I have to do this up to Column B = 100.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Coming from C/C++/Java type languages, the simple approach is for each row look at each value - something like this (not in any particular language)

```
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ROWS; i++)
{
    int bV = columns['B'][i]
    list<int> aV = columns['A'][i]
    if (aV.length != bV) {
        // If A doesn't have B items in it then
        // they can't possibly match.
        columns['C'][i] = 0;
    }
    else {
        // have to inspect each element
        int ok = 1
        for(int j = 1; j <= bV; j++) {
            if (aV[j] != j) {
                ok = 0
                break
            }
        }
        columns['C'][i] = ok
    }
}
```

If your language does list compares and the max allowed in column B isn't too high then you could predefine a list for each value of B and then just compare all the values of A

```
if (columns['A'][i] == expectedLists[colB]) {
    columns['C'][i]= 1
}
else {
    columns['C'][i]= 0
}
```

You could also do something similar with string representations of the list